# En un grupo de estudiantes, ¿Cómo puedo asignar compañeros a cada uno?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

En un arreglo de estudiantes

```
var estudiantes = [
    { NombreEstudiante: "Jimena Asis Camacho", id: "12" , codigoCurso: "282376"},
    { NombreEstudiante: "María Fernanda Quiñones Ospino", id: "13" , codigoCurso: "282376"},
    { NombreEstudiante: "Dina Luz Vergara Buelvas", id: "25" , codigoCurso: "282376"},
    { NombreEstudiante: "Estefania palma Murillo", id: "32" , codigoCurso: "282376"},
    { NombreEstudiante: "Deiber junior Miranda guerra", id: "33" , codigoCurso: "282376"},
    { NombreEstudiante: "Natalia Zarick Osorio Pedroza", id: "39" , codigoCurso: "282376"}
];
```

Quisiera generar compañeros, para cada estudiante con las siguientes condiciones

> Los estudiantes no deben poder seleccionarse a sí mismos como compañeros.
> No se debe poder seleccionar a un compañero que ya ha sido asignado a otro estudiante.
> Cuando selecciona un compañero, esa opción debe desaparecer de los demás campos de selección.
> Si en un select ya asignado se deselecciona al compañero o selecciona a otro, la opción deseleccionada debe volver a aparecer en los demás campos de selección.

algo más o menos así estoy buscando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento solo he logrado crear esa parte (la de la imagen) genero la tabla que recorre el arreglo, imprime uno por uno al estudiante, y en compañero llena el select con todos los valores del arreglo, y he logrado que quite al seleccionado de los demás selcts, pero no he podido hacer que vuelva si deselecciono, por ello no coloco el codigo, por si tienen otro enfoque.

Modificado...
Comparto código

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h1>Selección de Compañeros</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="students-table-body">
            <!-- La tabla se llenará dinámicamente aquí -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    var estudiantes = [
        { NombreEstudiante: "Jimena Asis Camacho", id: "12", codigoCurso: "282376" },
        { NombreEstudiante: "María Fernanda Quiñones Ospino", id: "13", codigoCurso: "282376" },
        { NombreEstudiante: "Dina Luz Vergara Buelvas", id: "25", codigoCurso: "282376" },
        { NombreEstudiante: "Estefania palma Murillo", id: "32", codigoCurso: "282376" },
        { NombreEstudiante: "Deiber junior Miranda guerra", id: "33", codigoCurso: "282376" },
        { NombreEstudiante: "Natalia Zarick Osorio Pedroza", id: "39", codigoCurso: "282376"  }
    ];

    // Crear la tabla y los selects dinámicamente
    var tabla = document.querySelector('table tbody');

    estudiantes.forEach(function(estudiante) {
        var fila = document.createElement('tr');

        // Celda de estudiante
        var celdaEstudiante = document.createElement('td');
        celdaEstudiante.textContent = estudiante.NombreEstudiante;
        fila.appendChild(celdaEstudiante);

        // Celda de compañero con select
        var celdaCompanero = document.createElement('td');
        var select = document.createElement('select');
        select.name = 'companero'; // Nombre del select para identificarlo
        select.classList.add('form-select'); // Agregar clases de Bootstrap u otros estilos
        var opcionPorDefecto = document.createElement('option');
        opcionPorDefecto.value = ''; // Valor por defecto vacío
        opcionPorDefecto.textContent = 'Seleccione...'; // Texto por defecto
        select.appendChild(opcionPorDefecto);

        // Agregar opciones de compañeros disponibles
        estudiantes.forEach(function(comp) {
            if (comp.id !== estudiante.id) { // Evitar que el estudiante sea su propio compañero
                var opcion = document.createElement('option');
                opcion.value = comp.id;
                opcion.textContent = comp.NombreEstudiante;
                select.appendChild(opcion);
            }
        });

        celdaCompanero.appendChild(select);
        fila.appendChild(celdaCompanero);

        tabla.appendChild(fila);
    });

    // Agregar evento para actualizar los selects cuando se realiza una selección
    document.querySelectorAll('select[name="companero"]').forEach(function(select) {
        select.addEventListener('change', function() {
            // Obtener el valor seleccionado
            var seleccion = this.value;

            // Actualizar los demás selects
            document.querySelectorAll('select[name="companero"]').forEach(function(otroSelect) {
                // Excluir el select actual
                if (otroSelect !== select) {
                    // Buscar la opción con el mismo valor en los demás selects y eliminarla
                    var opcion = otroSelect.querySelector('option[value="' + seleccion + '"]');
                    if (opcion) {
                        otroSelect.removeChild(opcion);
                    }

                    // Si se selecciona "Seleccione..." en el actual, restaurar la opción en los demás selects
                    if (seleccion === '') {
                        var opcionPorDefecto = document.createElement('option');
                        opcionPorDefecto.value = '';
                        opcionPorDefecto.textContent = 'Seleccione...';
                        otroSelect.appendChild(opcionPorDefecto);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });

    // Inicializa Select2 en los selectores de compañeros
    $('.select2').select2();
</script>
```

Intenté usar Select2 pues en mi busqueda me pareció que podía ayudarme.

Comment: He editado la pregunta colocando el código, estimado.

Comment: Ok, comparto el codigo un poco más segmentado entre Html y el JS

Answer (score 0):

Improvisé una solución usando AlpineJS para que se comporte reactivamente, y declarativamente en vez de imperativamente.

Cumple con:

- Genera las filas dinámicamente acorde al arreglo de estudiantes que hayas declarado
- Para cada fila, genera un select cuyas opciones se llenan dinámicamente con los compañeros disponibles
- Recalcula las opciones disponibles tomando los estudiantes libres que no sean el que está eligiendo
- Al elegir un valor, se realiza la selección complementaria (si mi compañero es A, entonces el compaero de A soy yo). De modo que no puedan producirse referencias que no sean mútuamente consistentes.
- Al liberar a mi compañero, mi compañero también queda sin pareja.

Tuve que hacerle algunos arreglos del tipo "palitos de fósforo y cinta adhesiva" como por ejemplo:

- Detectar el evento de quitar a mi pareja para dejar a ella sin pareja también (la reactividad no me hizo caso en esto)
- Fijarme como pareja de mi pareja cuando selecciono una
- Computar el conjunto de opciones disponibles como "los estudiantes sin pareja + mi pareja" porque si mi pareja no es seleccionable, se me vacía el selector.

Toda la reactividad está hecha con [Alpine.js](https://alpinejs.dev/) que es un poco como jQuery pero llevado a nuestra época y con no más que una docena de métodos.

```js
var estudiantes = [{
    nombre: "Jimena Asis Camacho",
    id: "12",
    codigoCurso: "282376"
  },
  {
    nombre: "María Fernanda Quiñones Ospino",
    id: "13",
    codigoCurso: "282376"
  },
  {
    nombre: "Dina Luz Vergara Buelvas",
    id: "25",
    codigoCurso: "282376"
  },
  {
    nombre: "Estefania palma Murillo",
    id: "32",
    codigoCurso: "282376"
  },
  {
    nombre: "Deiber junior Miranda guerra",
    id: "33",
    codigoCurso: "282376"
  },
  {
    nombre: "Natalia Zarick Osorio Pedroza",
    id: "39",
    codigoCurso: "282376"
  }
];

// Crear la tabla y los selects dinámicamente
var tabla = document.querySelector('table tbody');


document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

  Alpine.store('estudiantes', {
    opciones: estudiantes,
    get ids_ocupados() {
      return this.opciones.map(o => o.partner_id)
    },
    get libres() {
      return this.opciones.filter(o => !this.ids_ocupados.includes(o.id))
    },
    findById(id) {
      return this.opciones.find(o => o.id == id) || {}
    },

    opcionesPara(id) {
      let companero_id = this.findById(id).partner_id
      return this.libres.filter(o => o.id != id).concat(this.findById(companero_id))
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.p-1 {
  padding: 0.15em;
}

.nombres {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}

.selectores {
  flex-basis: 300px;
}

small {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>


<div x-data id="selectores_wrapper">
  <template x-for="estudiante in $store.estudiantes.opciones" :key="estudiante.id">

    <div class="flex p-1" x-data="{
 get companero_seleccionado() {
    return  this.me.partner_id;
 },
 get me() {
   return this.$store.estudiantes.findById(estudiante.id)||{};
 },
 init() {
    this.$watch('companero_seleccionado',(newVal,oldVal) => {
    if(newVal==oldVal) return;
          let ex_companero=this.$store.estudiantes.findById(oldVal),
             new_companero=this.$store.estudiantes.findById(newVal)||{}
          if(newVal==0 && ex_companero) {
            ex_companero.partner_id=0;
          }
          new_companero.partner_id=this.me.id
    });
 }
}">
      <div class="nombres" :title="estudiante.partner_id">
        <span x-text="estudiante.nombre"></span> 
        <template x-if="estudiante.partner_id"><small
            x-text="'Emparejado con '+$store.estudiantes.findById(estudiante.partner_id).nombre" /></template>
</div>


<div class="selectores">
  <select :name="'companero_de_'+estudiante.id" x-model="$store.estudiantes.findById(estudiante.id).partner_id">
    <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
    <template x-for="opcion in $store.estudiantes.opcionesPara(me.id)" :key="opcion.id">
            <option :value="opcion.id" x-text="opcion.nombre"></option>
          </template>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
</template>
</div>
```